# MongoDB get ObjectID from Object.class

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a object class:

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field;

@Document(
    collection = "users"
)

public class UsersData {
    @Field("Name")
    private String name;
    @Field("Address")
    private Address address;

}
```

Users are fetched using the `find(Query query,<T> entityClass)` operation and mapped onto UserData.class

Is there any way to get the objectID of the document representing a User.
(I am unable to edit UserData.java as it is a readonly file)

Comment: Sorry your question is little unclear.  You can’t add `private ObjectId id` in the `UsersData` class ?

Comment: Yes, I am unable to edit the UserData class as it is readonly (imported from package)

Comment: You could use either mongo template/repository  with projection to read the user id.

Comment: Can you change the way you query your data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use type `String` or `ObjectId`

```
public class UsersDataWithId extends UsersData {
    @Id
    private String id;
}
```

in alternative you can use `Document` type from MongoDB driver

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("users");
Document myDoc = collection.find().first();
myDoc.get("_id")
```